# If $f(x) \geq 0$, then $g(x) =f(x)+f'(x)+f''(x)+...+f^r(x) \geq 0$

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification, inequality, polynomials

I saw the other questions regarding this problem. I am trying to approach it a bit differently.

We can write $g(x)$ as $(D^r+D^{r-1}+D^{r-2}+...+D+1)f=g(x) \implies \frac{(D^{r+1}-1)}{(D-1)}f(x)=g(x) \implies f(x) = (1+D^{r+1}+...)[g(x)-g'(x)]=g(x)-g'(x) \geq 0$.

[$r$ =$deg f(x)$, $f(x)$ is a polynomial, greater or equal to zero for all $x$. ]

Now, $1 \geq g'(x)/g(x) \implies e^x \geq \ln{g(x)}$, which is defined for all $x$. Now, $g(x)$ has to be $>0$ $\forall x$, for that to occur.

Can someone take it from here?

Comment: Not sure the question is clear.  If $f(x)=x^2$ then $f(x)≥0$ but if $r=1$ then you have $g(x)=x^2+2x$ and that is not always $≥0$.

Comment: r is the degree of the polynomial

Comment: $f(x)$ is a polynomial?  Do you think it might be a good idea to include all the assumptions you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: So it's not true.. as @lulu gave an example of $x^2$ which is a polynomial..

Comment: @user123   Yes, but in my example I used a different $r$ than the degree.

Comment: @user123 well, in his case r is not the degree of f

Comment: Can you state all the assumptions? where did you write that $r$ is the degree of the polynomial?

Comment: The accepted answer to [this version of the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88260/sum-of-derivatives-of-a-polynomial) does what you want.  It's easier to work with the "infinite" sum of differential operators.

Comment: Thank you all! It has been really helpful!!