# Prove that if f is polynomial function then $f+f'+f''+\cdots+f^{(n)}\geqslant0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, problem-solving

> Suppose $f$ is a polynomial function with degree $n$ and $f(x)\geqslant0$ (so $n$ must be even). Prove that $f + f' + f'' +\ldots+f^{(n)}\geqslant0$.

Put $\;g(x)=f + f' + f'' +\ldots+f^{(n)}\;$ and $h(x)=f' + f'' +\ldots+f^{(n)}$.

Suppose $g(x) < 0$ for all $x$, then $f < -h(x)$. Since $h(x)$ is odd degree then $h(x)$ contain both negative and positive value implies that $f(x)<0$ for some $x$. Contradict the fact $f \geqslant0$.

Suppose $g(x) < 0$ for some $x$. Which mean $g(x) < 0$ for some $x$ and $g(x) > 0$ for others, then $g(x)=0$ for some $x$. Contradict assumption $g(x)<0$. Hence $g(x)\geqslant0$.

Is that a true proof? Is there any proof which doesn't use contradiction?

Comment: See [Sum of derivatives of a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/88260/42969) and its [linked questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/88260)

Comment: I cannot see how you derive a contradiction in the second case.

Comment: Since $g(x) < 0$ for all x is false. $g(x)$ must contain negative and positive value.

Comment: Yes, but why should that contradict the assumption that $g(x) < 0$ for some $x$?

Answer (score 0):

Your proof does not work. It seems that you want to give a proof of $g(x) \ge 0$ by contradiction. That is, you want to show that the assumption that $g(x) < 0$ for some $x$ leads to a contradiction.

Case 1. $g(x) < 0$ for all $x$.

This part is correct; you get a contradiction which shows that $g(x) \ge 0$ for some $x$.

Case 2. $g(x_0) < 0$ for some $x_0$, but $g(x_1) > 0$ for some other $x_1$.

I do not see why you consider this case; all you do with it is to deduce the existence of some $x_2$ with $g(x_2) = 0$. What you should do is to investigate the situation that $g(x_0) < 0$ for some $x_0$ and $g(x_1) \ge 0$ for some $x_1$. This also shows that $g(x_2) = 0$ for some $x_2$, but I do not know why you need this fact. Anyway, there is no contradiction here *unless you can show that $x_0 = x_1$ or $x_0 = x_2$*.

You made a logical mistake when you wrote

> Suppose $g(x) < 0$ for some $x$. Which mean $g(x) < 0$ for some $x$ and $g(x) > 0$ for others, then $g(x)=0$ for some $x$. Contradict assumption $g(x)<0$. Hence $g(x)\geqslant0$.

The two statements

- $g(x) < 0$ for some $x$
- $g(x)=0$ for some $x$

do not contradict each other. It seems that you think that taking both together is equivalent to

- $g(x) < 0$ and $g(x)=0$ for some $x$

which is not true.